# C# Listbox selected item text

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I am working on a wpf app, c#, in visual studio. My aim is to take the selected item text from a listbox on button press and add it to a list whilst also appending it to a text block. My code thus far:

```
bill.BillItems.Add(lstbxVeg.SelectedItem.ToString());
txtblkBill.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, bill.BillItems);
```

Where bill is the class name, BillItems the List name. I can see that items are indeed added to the text block, yet instead of the desired string relating to the listbox item selected, it reads System.Data.DataRowView. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: This is not the correct answer.

```
lstbxVeg.SelectedItem.Text.ToString()
```

I think the actual problem is this line:

```
txtblkBill.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, bill.BillItems);
```

You mentioned you want to append the value, this line is not accomplishing that.
I think you want to do this:

```
txtblkBill.Text += lstbxVeg.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

If that isn't the answer you should look up String.Join() as it takes a String[] not a List.

Comment: returns error - 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Text' and no extension... Which assembly ref would I need to use?

Comment: I looked at this again and your first line does appear to be correct if lstbxVeg is a ListBox. I updated my answer, hopefully it's correct now

Comment: I see what you did there! It's certainly appending, though I'm still seeing 'System.Data.DataRowView' as the appended text :(

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'll check out String.Join!